# Trackpad unable to press click after Security Update

Tags: trackpad

Apple issued a Security Update 3 days ago which was silently installed on my computer. I woke up and realized the trackpad doesn't give the press click feel again.

Before the update, I was able to just press the trackpad and would hear the click feedback, but after the update, the click is now silent.

My current Trackpad preferences - Mojave 10.4, MacBook Pro mid-2015:

[image: Trackpad Preferences]

Is there a way to fix this issue or remove the new trackpad drivers and reinstall the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do to fix this. Here are the basic steps that I would take on needed cases:

**Ditching Input plist Files:**

1. From the Mac OS Finder, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up “Go To Folder”
2. Enter the following path: **~/Library/Preferences/** and choose **Go**
3. Locate the following files manually, or use the Search box in the upper right corner and narrow down for ‘driver’ to find them – remove the ones that are relevant to your issue:

   ```
   com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist - Magic Trackpad
   com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist - Magic Mouse
   com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist - wired USB mouse
   com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
   com.apple.preference.trackpad.plist
   ```
4. Drag the appropriate files* to the desktop to make a backup of them, or just delete the files* if you’re comfortable with that
5. Leave the User Preferences folder and reboot the Mac

***Note**: You can get more specific if you want like only deleting the AppleHIDMouse.plist file if you are only using a USB mouse, or only removing BlueToothMultitouch.mouse if you only use a Magic Mouse, or you can ditch all of the plist files if you’re using all of them.

**If the above-listed solution didn’t help, then**

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.
Test after this.

If this doesn't help then at last try to:

**Reset the SMC on Mac**

First, shut down your Mac and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Release all keys. And, Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

**Start up in safe mode**

Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. The Apple logo appears on your display.

Release the <kbd>Shift</kbd>  key when you see the login window. If your startup disk is encrypted with FileVault, you might be asked to log in twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the Finder.

To leave safe mode, restart your Mac without pressing any keys during startup.